# How to slide div, checked the input checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to slide the div in jquery when checked the check box. but not working

how can i do this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".filter").prop('checked')(function(){
        $("p").slideToggle();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="checkbox" name="checkd" class="filter">
<p>Slider div</p>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(".filter").on('change', function () {
    $("p").slideToggle();
});
```

[**jsfiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/g280xdcx/)

Answer (score 5):

```
$(".filter").on('change', function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked'))
        $("p").slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: Use `$(this).is(':checked')` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this is what you looking for

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".filter").on('change', function () {

        $("p").slideToggle();
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="checkbox" name="checkd" class="filter">
<p style="display:none;">Slider div</p>



</body>
</html>
```